Busboy on file does not get fired when there are parenthesis in the file name
I am using busboy within firebase cloud functions. When there are parenthesis within the file name,(eg sample (1).pdf) the code halts before firing bb.on() event and eventually the function throws a timeout error.Below is the code snippet for it.
    const bb = Busboy({
      headers: req.headers,
      limits: {
        fileSize: fileLimit * 1024 * 1024,
      },
    });
 
  console.log("here before busboy");
    bb.on(
      "file",
      async (
        name: string,
        file: NodeJS.ReadableStream,
        info: FileInfo,
        fieldname:string
      ) => {
  console.log(`file name ${info.filename}`);
  console.log(`field name ${fieldname}`)
  const { filename, mimeType } = info;

In above code, the file name console log inside bb.on() doesn't get fired and hence file name doesn't get logged. It works when there is no parenthesis within the file name.
What I tried and what happened.

Sanitising the filename inside the bb.on() listener. However the bb.on() does not fire and the sanitising is not done.

Console logging req.file.filename and req.file.originalname. gives me undefined while req.body provides the content buffer.

Uploading a file with an HTTP client like Postman works fine. It is only when the file is uploaded from mobile application or in our case, using axios.


